# Given a function like $y = cx^{2}$ how do I get the differential $xy'$?

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives

I'm reading "Differential Equations with Applications and Historical Notes". At the very beggining of the book, it ask you to verify the following:

If $y = cx^{2}$ then $xy' = 2y$.

I don't really get what this notation means or how to go about the differentiation. I know basic differentiation rules like $\frac{\partial cx^{2}}{\partial x} = 2cx$, but I don't know how to get to that result (or what is actually asking with $xy'$). Could someone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$y'=\frac {dy}{dx}=2cx$$

$$xy'=2cx^2=2y$$

Comment: Oh, I see. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

In the task of finding a differential equations for this family of functions, one systematic way is to isolate the constant and then take the derivative. As the derivative of a constant is zero, this eliminates the constant from the equation.
$$
c=\frac{y(x)}{x^2}\implies 0=\frac{y'(x)}{x^2}-2\frac{y(x)}{x^3}.
$$
Next make this free of denominators.